# Go around nesting limit of fold expressions

Tags: c++, c++17

I am using the following code to build the "lookup table." Unfortunately, GCC refuses to compile it with the message `Instantiating fold expression with 581 arguments exceeded expression nesting limit of 256`.

```
template<std::size_t ...parameters>
static constexpr auto buildOffsets(std::index_sequence<parameters...>)
{
    constexpr std::array<uint16_t, sizeof...(parameters)> out = {
            ((parameter_traits::offset_of<static_cast<ParameterId>(parameters)>), ...)
    };
    return out;
}
```

Any idea how I could get around this limit? Is there any other way how to build this array?

Comment: What's inside `offset_of`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `template<ParameterId id> static constexpr auto offset_of = offsetofHelper<static_cast<ParameterId>(0), id>();` It just iterates over parameter entries <0;id) and sums their sizes together. offsetofHelper<> returns std::size_t

Comment: @Quest Iterating over data types and summing them together doesn't give you the offset within a structure (there's padding and alignment). Suggest using `offsetof` macro.

Comment: @lorro it is not an offset within a structure but inside a packet of data coming from the internet. True, we cast that to a structure at some point although it has a packed padding

Comment: @Quest Ok, might work.

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you replace it with `out = {static_cast<uint16_t>(parameter_traits::offset_of<static_cast<ParameterId>(parameters)>)...};` ?

Comment: Btw, can you provide a [mre] and tell us what version of g++ you are using?

Comment: The fact you use a comma fold expression to instantiate a lookup table is wrong. A fold expression is **one** initializer. That's not much of a lookup table.

Comment: This seems like a typo for what @TedLyngmo suggested as explained by the comment above. Of course there could still be a limit imposed by the compiler, but I would expect it not to be that low. But the error message is referring to _nesting_, so you might have some unintended recursion in there as well (which we can not determine since you are not showing the whole code).

Answer (score 2):

If someone is looking at this and wondering how to fix, the problem is not the template depth limit but the parenthesis depth limit as seen [in this discussion](https://reviews.llvm.org/D86936).

Clang uses that limit by default for fold expressions and you can raise it with `-fbracket-depth=N` as [described here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-implementation-limits).

Once you apply that the error messages will disappear.